# ADF Copy Activity from Oracle to ASQL - Logging failed error SessionLogFailToWriteLog

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have existing pipeline copying data from Oracle to Azure SQL executing successfully. Then added logging with level = Warning and mode = Reliable, see below.
But pipeline stuck at source and eventually failed, because pipeline timeout set to 15 mins. Error messages received is as below.

Did I miss out some configs? Please provide some advice as to why this is the case, thanks!

ADF logging settings

[image]

Copy failed at Source

[image]

```
Operation on target AC_COPY_SRC_TO_STG failed: ErrorCode=SessionLogFailToWriteLog,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Write log is failed with error message: 'Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException: ADLS Gen2 operation failed for: An error occurred while sending the request.. Account: 'storageAccount'. FileSystem: 'raw'.. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.41.33.170:443
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalEndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Rest.RetryAfterDelegatingHandler.<SendAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Rest.RetryDelegatingHandler.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<<SendAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Rest.RetryDelegatingHandler.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Data.RequestHandler.<SendAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Data.AzureDfsClient.<GetFilesystemPropertiesWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__42.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Data.AzureDfsClientExtensions.<GetFilesystemPropertiesAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Data.AzureDfsClientExtensions.GetFilesystemProperties(IAzureDfsClient operations, String filesystem, String resource, String xMsClientRequestId, Nullable`1 timeout, String xMsDate)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Data.BlobFSClient.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<IsFileSystemExist>b__1()
   at Microsoft.Rest.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction[TResult](Func`1 func)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Data.BlobFSClient.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<IsFileSystemExist>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Data.ExceptionHandler.ExecuteAction[TResult](Func`1 func, String fileSystem, String path, String actionName)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Data.ExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception ex, String fileSystem, String path, String actionName)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Data.ExceptionHandler.ExecuteAction[TResult](Func`1 func, String fileSystem, String path, String actionName)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Data.BlobFSClient.IsFileSystemExist(String filesystem, Boolean swallowForbiddenError, Boolean useListPathApi)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Data.BlobFSClient.CreateFileSystemIfNotExist(String filesystem, Boolean swallowForbiddenError, Boolean useListPathApiToCheckFileSystemExist)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.BlobFSMultipartSink..ctor(AzureBlobFSConnection connection, AzureBlobFSWriteInternalSettings writeSettings)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.AzureBlobFSConnection.CreateSink(IDictionary`2 properties)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.BinarySinkStageProcessor..ctor(PluginRegistration plugins, IDictionary`2 stageProperties, BinaryTelemetryCollector telemetryCollector)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.Provider.HybirdRuntimeBinaryWriter.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<ProcessCommandSettings>b__1()
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.PipelineProcessStage`3.CreateProcessor(Func`1 createNextProcessor)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.PipelineProcessStageProcessor`2.Process(TInput data)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.Provider.HybridRuntimeCommand.ExecuteBinaryWriter(IEnumerable`1 data)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.FileBasedLogHandler.CreateEmptyLogFile(Int32 currFileIndex)'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'
```

I tried disable the logging and the pipeline was success again.

Comment: When you click test connection, is the connection successful?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the error you are facing it can be because of the data factory is not able to communicate with ADLS. The error message also suggests that the issue may be related to the **inability to connect to a specific server with the IP address "10.41.33.170"**.

To resolve this:

- Check to see sure the ADLS Gen2 account is set up correctly and is reachable.
- Verify the application's and the ADLS Gen2 account's network connectivity.
- Check to see if the firewall rules are preventing access to the server at IP 10.41.33.170.

**You can add This Address in storage account firewall as below:**

[image]

**I also tried with similar settings and it's working fine for me.**

[image]